# SMTP : Email are not getting delivered

Tags: 7, emails

I have a SMTP Authentication Support 7.x-1.0 module in D7. Its enabled and configured correctly with permissions.

Emails are not getting delived, I dont know what is the issue here. 
Am I missing something here?

Tried/checked following things:

1. SMTP server is running, tested it. From command line emails are getting delivered.
2. No change in any of the core Drupal 7 modules and in SMTP module.
3. No errors found in drupal reports/ smtp logs

   This is what I am getting when I try to check SMTP test email.

> ```
> - SMTP.module is active.     
>  - The configuration options have been saved.
>  - SMTP.module is active.
>  - A test e-mail has been sent to    testemail@mycompanydomain.com.
>  - You may want to check the logs for    any error messages.
> ```

Following is the debugging output.

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 mycompanydomain.com ESMTP Postfix " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "220 mycompanydomain.com ESMTP Postfix " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220 mycompanydomain.com ESMTP Postfix 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-mycompanydomain.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mycompanydomain.com " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ETRN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 DSN " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-mycompanydomain.com 250-PIPELINING 250-SIZE 250-ETRN 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-8BITMIME 250 DSN 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.1.0 Ok " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.1.0 Ok " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.0 Ok 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.1.5 Ok " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.1.5 Ok " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.1.5 Ok 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "354 End data with . " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "354 End data with . " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 End data with . 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 29B7262 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 29B7262 " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 29B7262 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 Bye " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "221 2.0.0 Bye " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: Are you using other mail related modules like [Mime Mail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) ?

Comment: @NoSssweat yes, am using MIME mail and its enabled

Comment: Do you need to authenticate to send with the SMTP mail server?  Sometimes the mail server needs a rule to whitelist the IP of/accept send requests from the webserver.   Also, you may want to check to make sure you're running the most up-to-date version of the SMTP module.   As of the date of this comment, version 7.x-1.7 is available and reflects several security updates 7.x-1.0 was released.